# Reading lines including space

Tags: python, file-io

I want to read file including spaces in each lines

My current code

> def data():
>
> ```
> f = open("save.aln")
>
> for line in f.readlines():
>
>     print "</br>"
>
>     print line
> ```

I am using python and output embedded in html

File to be read - http://pastebin.com/EaeKsyvg

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you paste your code into the question, so that we can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cgi
with open('save.aln') as f:
    for line in f:
        print cgi.escape(line) # escape <, >, &
        print '<br/>'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your problem is that you need space preserving in HTML. The simple solution would be to put your output between `<pre>` elemenets

```
def data(): 
    print "<pre>"
    f = open("save.aln") 
    for line in f.readlines(): 
        print line
    print "</pre>"
```

Note that in this case you don't need the `<br>` elements either, since the newline characters are also preserved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are faced with is that HTML ignores multiple whitespaces. @itsadok's solution is great. I upvoted it. But, it's not the only way to do this either.

If you want to explicitly turn those whitespaces into HTML whitespace characters, you could to this:

```
def data():
    f = open("save.aln")
    for line in f.readlines():
        print "<br />"
        print line.replace(" ", "&nbsp")
```

Cheers